# Using Wine to open Windows .exe

Tags: windows, macos, wine, c#

I apologize for repeating my question, but it was suggested that I ask it on this StackExchange site instead of stackoverflow:

[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860067/using-wine-to-open-windows-exe):

I have created a simple .NET 4.5 Entity Framework Winforms application with Visual Studio and would like to open it on OS X.

I have used Wine before to open .exe's in the past and am having difficulty this time around. I have downloaded the most recent version of Wine, as well as OS X.

When I attempt to open the .exe with Wine, nothing happens. No error messages. Nothing.

When I attempt to package the .exe with WineBottler, I get a popup that says "Prefix created successfully"; however, when I attempt to open the newly created file, again, nothing happens.

I am very new to using Wine and have noticed that there are WineTricks you can use, but I am not sure if that is necessary. Again, I used Wine before on a very simple app and it worked just fine without using any WineTricks, but I am not sure whether I should include them for this app.

I have googled for help, but have not found much. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you have the .NET 4.5 Framework installed in your Wine prefix (bottle)?

If not, then you need to use a predefined prefix that already has the .NET 4.5 Framework installed, or install it yourself.  Just like on Windows, you need to make sure all dependencies are installed for the program to work. For installing predefined prefixes, take a look [here](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/virtualization/run-windows-apps-on-your-mac-free-with-wine-bottler/).

If you already have the .NET framework installed in your prefix, then I suggest you try to run your program with wine from the command-line (Terminal.app) to observe any messages that print to stdout or stderr. Hopefully this can give you some clues.

I think you would enter the following to open your exe from Terminal:

```
/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine path/to/your/exe
```

For using WineBottler, you might find [this tutorial](http://ukblog.im-mobility.com/winebottler-run-windows-apps-macos) helpful.

If all else fails, you might want to consider using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) to run your .NET program. Take a look at [this guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications).